# How to draw the symbol of a pseudo-random number generator (prng)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a pseudo-random number generator. I found this image at a [paper](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01236602/document) and now I want to know how it draws this beautiful image.

Is there a special library for this? I didn't something at my search. Maybe you have few ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `trapezium` shape from the `shapes.geometric` library can be convenient for this case. You will need to add `rounded corners` option also to get these nice rounded edges.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, rounded corners=7pt]  
  \node(T)  [trapezium, inner xsep=1.5pt, minimum height=4em, rotate=-90, draw,label=center:\textsf{next}] {};
  \node(S)  at(-2,0) {$S$};
  \node(S') at(2,0)  {$S'$};
  \node(R)  at(2,-1) {$R$};
  \draw [->](S) -- (T);
  \draw [->](T) -- (S');
  \draw [->](T.90) to[out=0,in=150] (R);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]